# Attach extras to CKAN resources?

Tags: ckan

Can I attach extras to CKAN resources? I noticed that `ckan.model.Resource` has an `extras` property, and so I tried to make a resource using something like this:

```
resource = {
    "package_id": "my-package-id",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "name": "Google",
    "extras": [
        { "key": "myextra", "value": "my extra content" }
    ]
}

from ckan.plugins import toolkit
toolkit.get_action("resource_create")(faked_context, resource)
```

I followed along as the logic function eventually ended up running `package_update`, but failed with `ValidationError: {u'  junk': u'The input field __junk was not expected.'}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the key "extras" for resource extras, just add whatever arbitrary key-value pairs you want as top-level keys in the resource dict, and they will be converted to resource extras. For example, I think this should work:

```
resource = {
    "package_id": "my-package-id",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "name": "Google",
    "myextra": "my extra content"
}
```

At least, I just tried that over the API and it worked, so I think it'll work via the plugins toolkit like you're doing it as well. I guess this feature needs documenting, probably in the [resource_create() docstring](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/ckan.logic.action.create.html#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create).

(Note: this does *not* work for packages, for adding custom fields to packages see the [example_idatasetform extension](https://github.com/okfn/ckan/tree/release-v2.0/ckanext/example_idatasetform) that ships with CKAN.)

Comment: Note that you *can* add extras to packages without `IDatasetForm`, but you have to explicitly list them via `"extras": [{"key": "my-key", "value": "my-value"}]`.